# Pandas timestamps in ISO format cause Exasol error when importing

Tags: python, exasol

When using [pyexasol's](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/tree/master/pyexasol) `import_from_pandas(df)` for a DataFrame, `df`, which has a datetime column, Exasol (6.2) throws an error because it can't parse the ISO-formatted string representation of the dataframe column.  Specifically, the "+00:00" final characters are unparsable by Exasol.  My current workaround is to turn all pandas datetime columns into string columns, but that can cost a lot of time.

What's the right way to import datetime columns from Pandas dataframes into an existing Exasol table with a `TIMESTAMP` column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyEXASOL creator is here.

You may use `import_params` dictionary argument to pass additional parameters to `pandas.to_csv()` method which is used internally. One of such parameters is `date_format`. Just pass the right format compatible with Exasol.

I'll consider adding this parameter by default.

Hope it helps!